# Files.Get concatenated string value appears empty after helm template in Kubernetes Configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using a configmap with a dynamic filename defined as below. However, after I do helm template the value for the filename is empty:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: krb5-configmap
data:
  krb5.conf: |-
      {{ .Files.Get (printf "%s//krb5-%s.conf" .Values.kerberosConfigDirectory .Values.environment) | indent 4 }}
```

> kerberosConfigDirectory: kerberos-configs (set in Values.yaml)

> Folder structure:

k8s:

- templates

  - configmap.yaml
- kerberos-configs

  - krb5-dev.conf

> After helm template the data value looks like this:

```html
data:
  krb5.conf: |-
--
```

I can't figure out why the value for the filename is empty. Note that I'm able to run the helm template command successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `/` and extra      indentation in you file. Working example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: krb5-configmap
data:
  krb5.conf: |-
{{ .Files.Get (printf "%s/krb5-%s.conf" .Values.kerberosConfigDirectory .Values.environment) | indent 4 }}
```